# Calculator in different language in android

Tags: android, calculator

I am trying build a simple calculator in my language, e.g., Bengali, in Android Studio.

That means it will calculate Bengali digits, not English.

I don't know how this can be done. Layout is easy to implement but when it comes to calculation, I don't  know how can I do it. Any advice will helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Considering math is a universal language, symbols don't matter. You can build a normal calculator, and then use localization (ie localized strings) to input the Bengali numbers/symbols.

You can read about localization [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

As an example, from this link above:

You would create a string resource file for your new language:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-b+es/
           strings.xml
       mipmap/
           country_flag.png
       mipmap-b+es+ES/
           country_flag.png
```

and then do:

English strings (default locale), /values/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Spanish strings (es locale), /values-es/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello_world">¡Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you show any example of localized string,please

Comment: It just localize strings,but here I need integer to be localized

Comment: There are functions called `Integer.parseInt(String i)` and `String.valueOf(int num)`. Use them.

Comment: I tried but i am unable to find a solution. here is the layout of my English calculator:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/H63XZ.png 
 and code sample :  https://pastebin.com/kWCtqcTc

Answer (score 0):

The logic is very simple. Take input from the user in bengali or in any language. Then, you need to extract the bengali digits one by one and convert them into english. Then do the calculation as it is done in english. Again, convert the result of the calculation into bengali and display it to the user.